How to re-open a bottomsheet if I'm closing it first in a recursive call?
So when I press the Try Again button and the onPressed method is called in the else statement, I want to close the current bottomsheet first and then make the recursive call. Currently the recursive call is made and the bottomsheet is closed but the new bottomsheet does not re appears.
Solution that I have tried :

Adding a future delay between the Navigator.pop(context) and the recursive call.

Future<void> handleBuyerCall(
    BuildContext context,
    Kms kms,
    NumberMasking numberMasking,
  ) async {
    if (kms.Value != "") {
      final phone = await numberMasking
          .getNumberMasking(kms.Value!);

      if (phone != null) {
        await showModalBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) => CustomBottomSheet(
            onPressed: () {
              launchCall(phone);
            },
            imgUrl: "assets/images/green_tick.svg",
            heading: "Connection Established",
            subHeading:
                "Please click on the below option to place a call to the buyer",
            text: "Call Buyer",
            twoCta: false,
          ),
        );
      } else {
        if (context.mounted) {
          await showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) => CustomBottomSheet(
              onPressed: () {
                 Navigator.of(context).pop();
                 handleBuyerCall(
                    context, kms, numberMasking);
              },
              imgUrl: "assets/images/cross.svg",
              heading: "Failed to Connect",
              subHeading:
                  "Please click on the below option to place a call to the buyer",
              text: "Try Again",
              text1: "Back",
              twoCta: true,
            ),
          );
        }
      }
    }
  }


Did you make sure to await the Future.delayed when you tried that?

Yes I did tried with await.

I hope you're sure that final phone = await numberMasking           .getNumberMasking(kms.Value!); is not null after your recursive call. It might be the cause of having no new bottomSheet appearing after a recursive call.

Also, don't forget to wrap your new bottomSheet with if (context.mounted) { ... }

Yes I have thoroughly checked it's not null.

Finally using Future.microtask and handling navigator logic worked.
onPressed: () {
Navigator.pop(context);
Future.microtask(() => handleBuyerCall(
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).context,
kms,
numberMasking));
          },

